# How to repair the corrupted image below using opencv, python, numpy and necessary libraries

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

[image]

```
import cv2

damaged_image = cv2.imread("Corrupted.png")
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png", 0)

output = cv2.inpaint(damaged_image, mask, 1, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imshow('test', output)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I couldn't generate mask with python, i have drawn the mask by using Paint as you can see it is not perfect.

[image]

After this code i get this output:

[image]

the repaired image should look similar to this picture:

[image]

Comment: For the yellow bands, you can certainly use a FFT analysis so to remove them. Then, for the curved blue lines, inpainting is indeed certainly the way to go. Note that fixing the yellow bands before can help you to get better results as you could certainly use inpainting only on the blue channel. Finally, you can tweak the contrast or more generally do an automatic level-analysis (which require the computation of the histograms).

Comment: The hazy bands cannot be removed by using inpainting. I doubt that FFT processing will remove them unless they are very regular.

Comment: @fmw42 The bands are very regular, my guess is that they’re generated on purpose as an example application of the FFT.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I would have to look at an FFT spectrum image to see if there is anything obvious that could be removed by notch filtering.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. See my ADDITION in my answer below where I added an FFT spectrum and attempt at notch filtering, though I see nothing that I would attribute to the haze if regular and broadly spaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The question was how to recover the original image by removing the various artifacts/defects.*

I have converted my Imagemagick-based analysis in to Python/OpenCV full analysis and code below.

**Here is the input**

[image]

We can see scratches and some hazy bands. So lets investigate further by separating the channels

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
```

Blue channel:

[image]

Green channel:

[image]

Red channel:

[image]

We can see:

1. scratches in the blue channel
2. brightness variation banding in the green channel
3. diagonal texture-like pattern in the red channel

So lets take each channel one at a time starting with the easiest to fix, which is the blue channel.

**Blue channel with scratches needs inpainting.**

So lets stretch it to full dynamic range for easy thresholding. Then threshold it at white (254) to get the scratches isolated as a mask.

```
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(b, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Blue scratch mask:

[image]

Now apply inpainting.

```
b_inpaint = cv2.inpaint(b, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

Inpainted Blue channel:

[image]

**Red channel with diagonal pattern needs DFT notch filtering**

So lets examine the DFT spectrum.

First, convert the red channel to floats and do dft saving it as complex output

```
r_dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(r), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
```

Then apply a shift of the origin from the upper left corner to the center.

```
r_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(r_dft)
```

Then extract the magnitude and phase images

```
r_mag, r_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(r_dft_shift[:,:,0], r_dft_shift[:,:,1])
```

Now compute the spectrum via a log and stretch it to full dynamic range

```
r_spec = np.log(r_mag)
r_spec = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(r_spec, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Red channel spectrum:

[image]

In the spectrum of the red channel, we can see 2 pairs of dots at about 45 degree angle on opposite sides of the center. So lets threshold it to form a mask that includes just the just the 2 pairs of dots removing the brighter spots at the center (which are the low frequencies in the image). Finally, we invert the mask.

```
mask2 = cv2.threshold(r_spec, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
delta = 20
mask2[255-delta:255+delta, 255-delta:255+delta] = 0
mask2i = cv2.bitwise_not(mask2)
```

Red channel mask before inverting, for ease in viewing:

[image]

Now we can apply the mask to the magnitude via multiplication.

```
mask2i = mask2i.astype(np.float32) / 255
r_mag_masked = cv2.multiply(r_mag, mask2i)
```

Next, convert the magnitude and phase into cartesian real and imaginary components.

```
r_real, r_imag = cv2.polarToCart(r_mag_masked, r_phase)
```

Then combine the cartesian components into one complex image.

```
r_complex = cv2.merge([r_real, r_imag])
```

Then shift the origin from the center back to the upper left corner.

```
r_complex_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(r_complex)
```

Finally, do the IDFT with normalization saving it as real output to create the notch filtered result.

```
r_notch = cv2.idft(r_complex_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
r_notch = r_notch.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Red channel notch filtered:

[image]

**The Green channel with banding might need DFT notch filtering**

So convert the green channel to floats and do dft saving it as complex output. Then apply a shift of the origin from the upper left corner to the center of image. Then extract the magnitude and phase images. Then compute the spectrum and stretch it to full dynamic range. This is the same as we did above for the red channel.

```
g_dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(g), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
g_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(g_dft)
g_mag, g_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(g_dft_shift[:,:,0], g_dft_shift[:,:,1])
g_spec = np.log(g_mag)
g_spec = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(g_spec, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Green channel spectrum:

[image]

But there does not appear to be any obvious bright feature to notch in the spectrum, likely because the amplitude of the wave pattern is too low (it is too faint). So lets take a different approach.

Lets guess that the hazy bands in the green channel image are from a sinusoidal wave modulation. Looking at the original green channel, it appears that there are 5 wavelength bands. So lets create a sinusoidal image with 5 wave bands.

Create a 1D linear ramp image in y. Then create a 1D sinusoid along the y axis from the ramp and tile it out (repeat it) horizontally to fill out the sinusoid image. (Note, it is actually created along x and then transposed to y)

```
y = np.arange(h, dtype=np.float32)
waves = h/5
phase = 90  (makes it a cosine from the top downward)
y_sinusoid = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (y/waves + phase/360))
y_sinusoid = np.tile(y_sinusoid, (w,1)).transpose()
```

Sinusoid Image (after scaling to uint8):

[image]

This pattern seems to match that in the green channel (apart from the amplitude, which does not matter). So lets get its spectrum (as before).

Apply DFT to the sinusoid image saving as complex output. Then apply a shift of the origin from the upper left corner to the center of image. Then compute the magnitude and phase images. Then compute the spectrum and stretch it to full dynamic range.

```
sinusoid_dft = cv2.dft(y_sinusoid, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
sinusoid_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(sinusoid_dft)
sinusoid_mag, sinusoid_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(sinusoid_dft_shift[:,:,0], sinusoid_dft_shift[:,:,1])
sinusoid_spectrum = np.log(sinusoid_mag)
sinusoid_spectrum = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(sinusoid_spectrum, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Spectrum image of sinusoid image:

[image]

The expected (ideal) spectrum for a sinusoid of one wavelength (or frequency) should be just the two brightest dots. So lets extract that region and insert it into a fully black image. Then blank out the brighter center, so we do not affect the overall gray level. Then threshold it to form a mask. And finally invert the mask.

```
mask3 = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)
mask3[255-10:255+11, 255-1:255+2] = sinusoid_spectrum[255-10:255+11, 255-1:255+2]
mask3[255-1:255+2, 255-1:255+2] = 0
mask3 = cv2.threshold(mask3, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
mask3i = cv2.bitwise_not(mask3)
```

Green channel mask before inverting, for ease in viewing:

[image]

Next, apply the mask to the magnitude. Then convert the modified magnitude and original phase into cartesian real and imaginary components. Then combine the cartesian components into one complex image. Then shift the origin from the center to the upper left corner. Finally, perform the IDFT with normalization saving the result as real output as the notch filtered result.

```
mask3i = mask3i.astype(np.float32) / 255
g_mag_masked = cv2.multiply(g_mag, mask3i)
g_real, g_imag = cv2.polarToCart(g_mag_masked, g_phase)
g_complex = cv2.merge([g_real, g_imag])
g_complex_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(g_complex)
g_notch = cv2.idft(g_complex_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
g_notch = g_notch.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Green channel notch filtered result:

[image]

**Now recombine the three modified color channels**

```
bgr = cv2.merge([b_inpaint, g_notch, r_notch])
```

Recombined blue, green, and red channels after processing:

[image]

**Finally, stretch each channel to full dynamic range to improve brightness/contrast and recombine again for a better result**

```
b_inpaint = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(b_inpaint, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
g_notch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(g_notch, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
r_notch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(r_notch, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
bgr2 = cv2.merge([b_inpaint, g_notch, r_notch])
```

Stretched and Recombined blue, green, and red channels after processing:

[image]

**Here is the full script:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# Read the input
img = cv2.imread('fruit.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# We can see scratches and some hazy bands.
# So lets investigate further by separating the channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
cv2.imshow('blue', b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('green', g)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('red', r)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# We can see:
# 1) scratches in the blue channel
# 2) diagonal texture-like pattern in the red channel
# 3) brightness variation banding in the green channel

# So lets take each channel one at a time.


# ---- Blue channel needs inpainting. ----
 
# So lets stretch to full dynamic range, 
# Then threshold it to get the scratches isolated as a mask
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(b, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imshow('blue inpaint mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Now apply inpainting
b_inpaint = cv2.inpaint(b, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imshow('blue inpainted', b_inpaint)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# ---- Red channel needs DFT notch filtering ----

# So lets examine the DFT spectrum

# Convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
r_dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(r), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# Apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
r_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(r_dft)

# Extract magnitude and phase images
r_mag, r_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(r_dft_shift[:,:,0], r_dft_shift[:,:,1])

# Get spectrum and stretch to full dynamic range
r_spec = np.log(r_mag)
r_spec = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(r_spec, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('red spectrum', r_spec)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# We can see 2 pairs of dots at about 45 degree angle on opposite sides of the center
# So lets try thresholding to extract them and remove the spots at the center, then invert
mask2 = cv2.threshold(r_spec, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
delta = 20
mask2[255-delta:255+delta, 255-delta:255+delta] = 0
cv2.imshow('red spectrum mask', mask2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
mask2i = cv2.bitwise_not(mask2)
cv2.imshow('red spectrum mask inverted', mask2i)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Now we can apply the mask to the magnitude
mask2i = mask2i.astype(np.float32) / 255
r_mag_masked = cv2.multiply(r_mag, mask2i)

# Now convert magnitude and phase into cartesian real and imaginary components
r_real, r_imag = cv2.polarToCart(r_mag_masked, r_phase)

# Combine cartesian components into one complex image
r_complex = cv2.merge([r_real, r_imag])

# Shift origin from center to upper left corner
r_complex_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(r_complex)

# Do idft with normalization saving as real output
r_notch = cv2.idft(r_complex_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
r_notch = r_notch.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('red notched', r_notch)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# ---- Green channel might need DFT notch filtering ----

# convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
g_dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(g), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# Apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
g_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(g_dft)

# Extract magnitude and phase images
g_mag, g_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(g_dft_shift[:,:,0], g_dft_shift[:,:,1])

# Get spectrum and stretch to full dynamic range
g_spec = np.log(g_mag)
g_spec = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(g_spec, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('green spectrum', g_spec)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# There does not appear to be any obvious place to notch.
# So lets guess that the hazy bands in the green channel image is a sinusoidal wave.
# Visually it looks like there are 5 wave bands. So lets create an image with 5 wave bands.

# Create ramp in y
y = np.arange(h, dtype=np.float32)

# Create sinusoid along y from ramp and tile out (repeat) horizontally
waves = h/5
phase = 90  # makes it a cosine from the top downward
y_sinusoid = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (y/waves + phase/360))
y_sinusoid = np.tile(y_sinusoid, (w,1)).transpose()
cv2.imshow('sinusoid', y_sinusoid)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# This pattern seems to match that in the green channel (apart from the amplitude, which does not matter)
# So lets get its spectrum

# Apply dft of sinusoid saving as complex output
sinusoid_dft = cv2.dft(y_sinusoid, flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# Apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
sinusoid_dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(sinusoid_dft)

# Extract magnitude and phase images
sinusoid_mag, sinusoid_phase = cv2.cartToPolar(sinusoid_dft_shift[:,:,0], sinusoid_dft_shift[:,:,1])

# Get spectrum and stretch to full dynamic range
sinusoid_spectrum = np.log(sinusoid_mag)
sinusoid_spectrum = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(sinusoid_spectrum, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('sinusoid spectrum', sinusoid_spectrum)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# The expected (ideal) spectrum for a sinusoid of one frequency should be just the two brightest dots.
# So lets extract that region and then mask out the center, threshold and invert
mask3 = np.zeros((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)
mask3[255-10:255+11, 255-1:255+2] = sinusoid_spectrum[255-10:255+11, 255-1:255+2]
mask3[255-1:255+2, 255-1:255+2] = 0
mask3 = cv2.threshold(mask3, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imshow('green spectrum mask', mask3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
mask3i = cv2.bitwise_not(mask3)
cv2.imshow('green spectrum mask inverted', mask3i)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Now we can apply the mask to the magnitude
mask3i = mask3i.astype(np.float32) / 255
g_mag_masked = cv2.multiply(g_mag, mask3i)

# Now convert magnitude and phase into cartesian real and imaginary components
g_real, g_imag = cv2.polarToCart(g_mag_masked, g_phase)

# Combine cartesian components into one complex image
g_complex = cv2.merge([g_real, g_imag])

# Shift origin from center to upper left corner
g_complex_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(g_complex)

# Do idft with normalization saving as real output
g_notch = cv2.idft(g_complex_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
g_notch = g_notch.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('green notched', g_notch)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# ---- Now recombine the three modified color channels ----
bgr = cv2.merge([b_inpaint, g_notch, r_notch])
cv2.imshow('recombined processed channels', bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)


# ---- Finally, stretch each channel to full dynamic range to improve brightness/contrast ----
b_inpaint = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(b_inpaint, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
g_notch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(g_notch, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
r_notch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(r_notch, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# Now combine the stretched channels
bgr2 = cv2.merge([b_inpaint, g_notch, r_notch])
cv2.imshow('recombined processed channels stretched', bgr2)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Save results
cv2.imwrite('fruit_blue_channel.png', b)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_green_channel.png', g)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_red_channel.png', r)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_blue_channel_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_blue_channel_inpainted.png', b_inpaint)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_red_spectrum.png', r_spec)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_red_channel_mask.png', mask2)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_red_channel_notched.png', r_notch)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_green_spectrum.png', g_spec)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_sinusoid.png', (255*y_sinusoid).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('fruit_sinusoid_spectrum.png', sinusoid_spectrum)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_green_channel_mask.png', mask3)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_green_channel_notched.png', g_notch)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_processed_channels_recombined.png', bgr)
cv2.imwrite('fruit_processed_channels_stretched_recombined.png', bgr2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from your inpainting in Python/OpenCV, I can mitigate your haze using my bash unix Imagemagick shell script that does spatially adaptive contrast enhancement.

Input:

[image]

```
space -m 0 -g 5 -w 50 fruit.png fruit_result.png
```

[image]

```
-m mixes the image with its mean (0 is no mixing)
-g is the maximum gain
-w is the window size in percent of the image dimensions
```

See [space](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/space/index.php)

Alternately, and probably better use CLAHE in Python/OpenCV.  Here is an example from Imagemgick

```
magick fruit.png -clahe 75x75%+256+3 fruit_result2.png
```

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is an FFT spectrum computed from Imagemagick:

```
convert fruit.png -colorspace gray -fft -delete 1 -evaluate log 100000 spectrum.png
```

[image]

Since the haze in the input is in horizontal bands (varying along y), then there should be a dense array of bright spots along y at the horizontal center. I do not see anything that stands out that is different along y than along x.  So either the effect is to faint (most likely) or not regular enough for FFT processing to remove without further information.

Nevertheless, here is a mask and the resulting notch filter result that assumes the haze array shows as the pairs of lines close to the center in x and in y.

Mask:

[image]

```
convert fruit.png -fft \
\( -clone 0 mask2.png -compose multiply -composite \) \
\( -clone 1 mask2.png -compose multiply -composite \) \
-delete 0,1 -ift fruit_notch2.png
```

Notched Filter Result (which I do not think shows significant improvement):

[image]

If one assumes the haze is in only one channel, then here are the red, green and blue channel spectra images. I do not see anything obvious in any one that would correlate to horizontal haze bands.

Red Spectrum:

[image]

Green Spectrum:

[image]

Blue Spectrum:

[image]

If I just notch the red channel (suggested by Cris Luengo), then I get the following, which does not show significant improvement.

Mask:

[image]

Notched Red Channel Only Result:

[image]

However, upon separating the channels of the input, I see that the scratches are in the blue channel and the haze bands are actually in the green channel. The red channel has some regular pattern at 45 degrees which does show as 2 pairs of bright dots in the red spectrum, which could be notched out. Here are all 3 channels. But I do not see anything in the green channel that I could attribute to the haze banding.

Red Input:

[image]

Green Input:

[image]

Blue Input:

[image]

Here is the result of notching the green channel only:

[image]

One other thought is that the haze banding is in the form of a sinusoid wave. One might be able to measure the wavelength and estimate the amplitude and perhaps do some kind of subtraction to remove it. Or compute the locations of the pattern in the spectrum and do notch filtering.

Following the latter train of thought, I made an sinusoid (cosine from the top) wave image having 5 wavelengths that appears to match the haze pattern (the phase should not matter, i.e. sine or cosine):

[image]

The spectrum is as follows (mostly 2 closely spaced dots one on each side of the DC point - middle of the image).

[image]

I then masked out the very center dot (the DC point -- representing the average value in the image) and inverted it to make a mask:

[image]

I then notched the green channel, which appears to have reduced the haze banding (compare this to the un-notched spectrum above):

[image]

And finally combined it with the red and green original channels.

[image]

To finish this, the red spectrum needs to be notched to remove the 2 pairs of bright dots that correspond to the diagonal noise pattern. And the blue channel of the original needs to be inpainted. I leave that to OP.

Comment: Did you try looking at the FFT of the red channel only? I’m away from my computer at the moment, otherwise I’d try it myself.

Comment: `@Cris Luengo` OK, I just checked the red channel (and the others) and notched the red channel, though I did not see anything I would expect to cause the haze bands. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: `@Cris Luengo` The haze banding is only in the green channel and the scratches are in the blue channel. The red channel has some regular pattern at 45 degrees which does show as 2 pairs of bright dots in the red spectrum.

Comment: Interesting! The hazing in the green channel is at a frequency that is likely quite strong in the input, so removing it completely maybe adds another similar pattern. Nice sleuthing!

Comment: I will try to do all 3 channel processing in Python/OpenCV tomorrow or over the weekend. Interesting problem. I wonder was this a homework assignment or challenge?

Comment: I have added a new answer that repairs all 3 channels of the input in Python/OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

for the blue lines you can simply use a median filter provided in open cv library. and for the other parts you need to use FFT analysis.